# Change CSS Property with Jquery Variable

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to use Jquery to change css.  The css property is kinda complicated so I'm not sure if my concatination is working or if there's another problem:

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var degrees = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 20;  //this is my variable

$('#p2').css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+degrees"deg)");
// this -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); is the property im trying to change
});
```

Comment: You are missing a `+` there. `"...e(" + degrees + "deg)");`

Comment: where should the + go?

Comment: awesome!! can you post this as a solution so i can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a small mistake. you're not appending it properly. notice the '+' after the degrees

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var degrees = Math.floor(Math.random() * 151) + 20;  //this is my variable

$('#p2').css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+ degrees +"deg)");
// this -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); is the property im trying to change
});
```